# How to save the output of PHP image processing

Tags: php

I'm not sure whether or not this function does what I intend it to do, but what I need is to create a thumbnail of an image in the folder.

```
$filename = '../images/' . $new_name;

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);

$new_width = $width / $height;

$new_height = 250 / $new_width;

$new_height = round($new_height);

$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor(250, $new_height);
$image_s = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image_s, 0, 0, 0, 0, 250, $new_height, $width, $height);

imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
```

So I need to save the final result to my folder, but not overwrite the original image. I found this function on the http://php.net/, but I have no idea as to how to save the image.

Answer (score 2):

```
imagejpeg($image_p, "path/to/dir/image.jpg", 100);
```

And that is all.

Comment: thanx a million! =) I had a real trouble creating thumbnails trying to run the function while the image is loading to the server... and then decided that it's better to run it after it has been uploaded. Will it affect the speed of the upload/processing?

Comment: When the image is not fully loaded on the server, you can't process it. The processing on the server goes in an instance. The only speed delimiter you really have to care about it the upload speed. Here the factors of your internet connection and the file size are the deciding factors. But there is nothing you can really do about that.